# Connecting to a database after creating it with Kotlin Exposed

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, kotlin-exposed

I'm using [jetbrains' exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) library to create and populate a database.

The database does not exist, and I am creating it. However I could not find a simple way to connect to the SQL engine, create a database and connect to that database without multiple connections. 
That sounds a little clunky. Is there a better way to do it maybe?

Here is a small example :

```
var db = Database.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user = "root", password = "aRootPassword")

transaction(db) { SchemaUtils.createDatabase("imdb") }

// avoid reconnect?
db = Database.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/imdb", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user = "root", password = "aRootPassword")

transaction(db) { SchemaUtils.create (TitleRatings) }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a connection pool, e.g. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). It pools database connections and reuses them. This gives you a huge performance boost compared to individually opened connections.

I usually wrap it in a simple class like this:

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import javax.sql.DataSource

public object DB {

    var db: DataSource = connect();

    public fun connect(): DataSource {
        val config = HikariConfig()
        config.jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308"
        config.username = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        config.password = "aRootPassword"
        config.driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

        return HikariDataSource(config)

    }
}
```

My transactions then look like this one:

```
transaction(Database.connect(DB.db)) {
   SchemaUtils.createDatabase("imdb")
}
```